# Raspbian/OctoPi File Recover

Tags: hardware, sd-card, server, file

I dropped my Pi on the SD Card slot. It broke and now I want to recover my files off of my SD Card, but I only see a boot partition with no relevant files inside. I was using OctoPi (3D Printing Server software running on Raspbian), and I want my Gcode files. How can I recover the files?

Comment: Your very First then you need to do is image your sd card. Once you do that do not tamper with the sd card, work solely with the image file you generate.  use ddrescue: sudo ddrescue /dev/sdCard recovery.iso
then run testdisk against the ISO file. (or whatever data recovery software you choose. This is standard data recovery proceedure.  Do not write anything else the to sd card.

Answer (score 2):

The files would be in an `ext4` partition. There are third party solutions which can read these on Windows or OS X.

They can be read on any Linux system, including a live CD.

Comment: Do you know which directory the files will be kept in? If not, what is the general directory for user's files? For example, in Windows C:\Users\{USER}.

Comment: @pisquaredtau what OS are you doing data recovery on? Windows cannot by default recognize linux partitions, and even the software to enable windows-linux partition reading, is frequently buggy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just pick up another Pi, honestly. Assuming your SD card is intact, that will be the easiest/simplest way to get back up and running again.